# Java. Как программно крутить таблицу?

Tags: java, view

Есть таблица JTable. Насколько я понял, scrollpane, в котором она лежит, создает ползунок прокрутки. Как его программно двигать? Пробовал

```
JScrollBar scroll = tableScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
scroll.setValue(100);
```

, но не работает

Answer (score 0):

Нашел

```
scroll.getViewport().setViewPosition(new Point(0,1000));
```